# Do we have office 2007 with xml and excel versions?

Tags: xml, ms-office, xls, xlsx

Do we have office 2007 files in two different version. for xml and excel version, what is the difference between these two files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that xml is an open format (You can read it even by notepad), excel format is not (You can only read it by Office Excel)

There are many other advantages, Find them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205%28v=office.12%29.aspx)